# How can I use custom AppEngine run configuration inside GWT run configuration? (IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.2)

Tags: java, debugging, google-app-engine, configuration, intellij-idea

How can I use custom AppEngine run configuration inside GWT run configuration ?

I need this in order to pass additional parameters to GAE Dev Server.

Here is how my configuration looks like

[image]

What is the purpose of "Server" combo-box then if there is no "test" configuration ?

I tried modifying GAE configuration in "Defaults" tree but it doesn't use it (my extra parameters are ignored).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

When you set 'AppEngine Dev' in 'Server' field IDEA set corresponding '-server' parameter in GWT Dev Mode and adds AppEngine's jars to the classpath so GWT Dev Mode will use AppEngine server instead of default one. If you want to pass additional JVM parameters to AppEngine you can specify they in 'VM parameters' field in GWT run configuration.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It says "Could not create the Java virtual machine. Unrecognized option: --address=127.0.0.1".

Comment: --address parameter should be passed to AppEngine not to its JVM. It seems that there are no way to pass parameters to AppEngine when it is started via GWT Dev Mode. However you can start AppEngine server using the separate AppEngine run configuration and then start GWT run configuration with -noserver parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can use two configurations but it's not the goal. It's too inconvinient to do.

Comment: I don't see how IDEA can help you in this case. GWT Run configuration just start GWT Dev mode and it doesn't allow to pass parameters to AppEngine (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#What_options_can_be_passed_to_development_mode).